# How to get differece between two times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the difference between two times. The first one is the current time object that I get using javascript date object `new Date()`
And the second one is a string like "20:30".
So suppose if current time is 18:00 then I just want the difference like that "2 hours and 30 mins left.
Thanks for any type of help.

Comment: I think you could read the question here.
[date-diff-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386175/date-diff-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check time difference in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function calculateTime() {

    var valuestop = $("select[name='timestop']").val();

    var timeStart = new Date().getTime();//current time
    var timeEnd = new Date(new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/') + ' ' + valuestop).getTime();//selected time
    console.log(timeStart + ' ' + timeEnd);
    var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart; //in ms
    var secDiff = hourDiff / 1000; //in s
    var minDiff = hourDiff / 60 / 1000; //in minutes
    var hDiff = hourDiff / 3600 / 1000; //in hours
    var humanReadable = {};
    humanReadable.hours = Math.floor(hDiff);
    humanReadable.minutes = Math.round(minDiff - 60 * humanReadable.hours);
    console.log(humanReadable); //{hours: 0, minutes: 30}
    $("p").html("Difference: <b>Hours: </b>" + humanReadable.hours + "<b>Minutes: </b>" + humanReadable.minutes);
  }
  $("select").change(calculateTime);
  calculateTime();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="timestop">
    <option value="00:00:00">12:00 am</option>
    <option value="01:00:00">1:00 am</option>
    <option value="02:00:00">2:00 am</option>
    <option value="03:00:00">3:00 am</option>
    <option value="04:00:00">4:00 am</option>
    <option value="05:00:00">5:00 am</option>
    <option value="06:00:00">6:00 am</option>
    <option value="07:00:00">7:00 am</option>
    <option value="08:00:00">8:00 am</option>
    <option value="09:00:00">9:00 am</option>
    <option value="10:00:00">10:00 am</option>
    <option value="11:00:00">11:00 am</option>
    <option value="12:00:00">12:00 pm</option>
    <option value="13:00:00">1:00 pm</option>
    <option value="14:00:00">2:00 pm</option>
    <option value="15:00:00">3:00 pm</option>
    <option value="16:00:00">4:00 pm</option>
    <option value="17:00:00">5:00 pm</option>
    <option value="18:00:00">6:00 pm</option>
    <option value="19:00:00">7:00 pm</option>
    <option value="20:00:00">8:00 pm</option>
    <option value="21:00:00">9:00 pm</option>
    <option value="22:00:00">10:00 pm</option>
    <option value="23:00:00">11:00 pm</option>
    </select>

<p> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use the library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) which can handle time/date-manipulation well.

Comment: Is there any way to do that using available javascript Date functions ?

Comment: @SKJajoriya  yes, you can parse the date with `Date` if you want, see this thread for example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

And the just compare the two dates and get the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
var date1 = new Date(2000, 0, 1, 20, 30);
var date2 = new Date(2000, 0, 1, 18, 0);

var diff = date1-date2;//milli seconds


var min = diff / 1000 / 60;
var r = min % 1;
var h=min/60;
var sec = Math.floor(r * 60);
if (sec < 10) {
    sec = '0'+sec;
}
    alert(min+'-'+ sec);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Date.Parse()` function with a string such as `Date.parse("1970 1 1 20:30")` to get a javascript date time, then follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript) on how to get the time difference between the two javascript date objects.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize functions that are available in `Date` object.

```
var origTime = '20:30'.split(':');
var dateA = new Date();
dateA.setHours(origTime[0]);
dateA.setMinutes(origTime[1]);
var dateB = new Date();
var hourDiff = Math.abs(dateA - dateB)/36e5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it using only vanilla Js:

```
var compareDate = new Date();
var timeParts = "20:30".split(":");
compareDate.setHours(Number(timeParts[0]));
compareDate.setMinutes(Number(timeParts[0]));
compareDate.setSeconds(0);
compareDate.setMilliseconds(0);

var diff = compareDate - new Date();
var diffInMinutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
var hours = Math.floor(diffInMinutes / 60);
var minutes = diffInMinutes % 60;

hours + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes left";
```

We're "normalizing" seconds and milliseconds by setting them to 0, otherwise they'll be whatever they were when `new Date()` was called.